# Erro ao compilar C no gcc: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc

Estou tentando compilar um arquivo.c mas não estou conseguindo.
Digito o seguinte comando:

```
gcc main.c -o HELLO
```

e aparece o seguinte erro:

```
gcc: error: main.c: No such file or directory
gcc:fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Fiz o seguinte no próprio bloco de notas:

```
include <stdio.h>

   int main()
    {
        printf("Hello World\n");
      return(0);
     }
```

O que fazer??

Comment: Você está na pasta que contém o arquivo `main.c`?

Comment: O arquivo ta no Desktop, tem diferença?

Comment: Claro que tem! Olhe a minha resposta

Comment: Você utiliza Linux ou Windows, no Linux normalmente dou os comandos `cd` para chegar até o local do arquivo e executar o comando.

Comment: No `Windows` também é `cd`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro diz que não conseguiu encontrar o arquivo **main.c**.

Para você compilar o arquivo, não basta entrar no *cmd* e digitar

> gcc arquivo.c -o executavel

Das duas uma, ou você precisa estar na pasta que o arquivo se encontra, ou precisa indicar o caminho completo do arquivo:

Exemplo (com o arquivo **main.c** no *Desktop*):

**Caminho completo**:

> gcc C:\Users\SeuUsuario\Desktop\main.c -o HELLO

**Mudando de diretório**:

> cd C:\Users\SeuUsuario\Desktop
>
> gcc main.c -o HELLO

Comment: Aaaaaah tendi, vlw!!

Comment: Funcionou certinho, muito obrigado :)